# R Plot points are Offset?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, offset, points

So I have a plot in R, but the points seem to be offset by a small amount... (maybe by 1 point to the right).

This is my code:

```
  x <- 0:30
  db<-dbinom(x, 30, 0.30)
  plot(x, db, type = "h", ylab=NULL)
  lines(x, db, type = "l", lty=2, ylab=NULL)
  points(db, y=NULL, col="red")
```

And here is the plot:

[image: R plot, points offset]

Am I calling the points() functions incorrectly or missing something out? I can't find anything on here or google... Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, if you supply no `y` argument, `points()` will plot the points at `x=1` to `x=length(data)`.  To fix that, modify you code as follows:

```
points(x, y = db, col="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set both x and y to align it properly.

Change

```
points(db, y=NULL, col="red")
```

To

```
points(x, db, col="red")
```